# Undefined reference when using <execution> in C++

Tags: c++, c++17, tbb

I'm trying to use the `<execution>` header from the C++ standard library. However, adding `#include <execution>` to my file causes the following error when I try to compile:

```sh
/usr/bin/ld: /tmp/ccO0ZngO.o: in function `tbb::interface7::task_arena::current_thread_index()':
/usr/include/tbb/task_arena.h:449: undefined reference to `tbb::interface7::internal::task_arena_base::internal_current_slot()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I am compiling using C++17 (using flag `-std=c++17`) and g++ version 9.3.0 on Ubuntu 20.04. I installed `libtbb-dev` using `apt` and have tried compiling with and without the flag `-ltbb` but get the same error either way.

(For reference my full compilation command is `g++ -std=c++17 -ltbb -g <source file> -o <output file>`)

Comment: `-ltbb` needs to go to the end of the command line. Also you may want to add `-pthread`, not sure about that.

Comment: Thanks, moving `-ltbb` to the end fixed it. It seems like `-pthread` isn't necessary though.